# production.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value {"exception":"[object]

Tags: laravel

I am getting error production.ERROR:

> Creating default object from empty value {"exception":"[object]

but I can not detect the error.

```php
$data = Deposit::where('status',0)->where('wallet', $request->address)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

if ($request->status>=1 || $request->status==2) 
{
     $data = Deposit::where('status',0)->where('wallet', $request->address)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
     $data->amount = $request->amount; // Here IS ERROR
     $data->status= 1;
     $data->update();
}
```

Comment: dont have amount in `$request`, `dd($request)` to check you getting amount or not from  request

Comment: @KaranSadana this is IPN off payment gateway . i am requesting

Comment: @KaranSadana and it is adding amount also in database but why error

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is not being set - your query constraints are not finding a record and returning `null`. You're then trying to set value `$data->amount` but as `$data` does not exist it's erroring.

Ensure that your query is correct and loading a Deposit record that exists, otherwise set `$data = new Deposit` to create a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
$data = Deposit::where('status',0)->where('wallet', $request->address)->first();
if(!empty($data)){
    $data->amount = $request->amount;
    $data->status= 1;
    $data->save();
}
```

As you are using first() there is a possibility that the object is empty. So when you are trying to update that empty object you are getting this error.